# 2005-2015 YA: Science Fiction/Romance: Book Set In Future. Augmented Reality, Teens Wear Headpieces That Display Messages Directly To Their Brains

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

Published 2005-2015
The main characters (teens) wear devices on their heads that are a brain-computer interface to display messages directly to their brains. The teen goes to a fancy party where there are large bubbles as decorations. The teen cleans houses to earn money.

Comment: When did you read this?  Physical book or e-book?  Do you remember the cover art or any character or place names?